# main content DIV is drifting upwards when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, resize

I am new to building websites and CSS, but am working on a project at http://www.profootballschedules.net.  I want to address a couple of formatting issues with divs.  Tried to look up other questions on here but nothing seemed to work.  If you'd like me to upload any code, please let me know, as I am very new to this whole process.

First, when resizing the browser, you'll notice that the main text heading drifts up above the allotted paper area, and doesn't stay level.  Not sure how to fix that - tried to tweak positioning to absolute on some of the divs containing the text, but it didn't do anything.  Also, I'd like to be able to resize the window and scroll around from left to right, but I can't get that to work either. I tried overflow on the body and some of the main divs, but no dice.

While you're looking, if you have any suggestions for increasing cross-browser compatibility, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using % for the padding-top in the .site-main class. Switch to pixels.

```
.site-main {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 600px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 926px;
}
```

Also, you have    overflow: hidden; that's removing the scrolling.

UPDATE:

Fix the wrapper %.

```
.site {
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 960px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. When I slowly resize the browser, do you notice how the div moves around from side-to-side a bit?  I'm having trouble keeping it centered between those two red thumbtacks.  Any suggestions for how to fix that?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I added a new update that fixes the issue. The site class it's in a div wrapper and it has min-width: 100%; while the interior is fixed px. That causes the issue when the windows is resized.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo - I'm still noticing a random jump in the div when the width of my browser crosses from 1120px to 1119px or smaller...do you notice how (when slowly resizing the browser) the div jumps to the left and is almost flush against the red thumbtack, instead of centered?  There's an odd jump and I don't know how to adjust that.

Comment: You are using media queries. Go to style.css look for @media screen and (max-width: 1119px) {...} (and smaller sizes) You are using percentages there. You need to change the class from a % to px. Change for other sizes too.

Comment: Hi Ricardo - still can't seem to get it to change. I'm going to have a separate website for mobile/tablet, so is there a way to turn off the media queries, or set it so that nothing changes when the width of my browser window drops from 1120 to 1119px? thanks!

Comment: Delete the media queries, and use fix sizes. Although I don't recommend having multiple websites. It will give you a  lot of work to maintain everything.

Answer (score 0):

Use px instead of % for the padding-top in .site-main. To enable scrolling, get rid of overflow:hidden and the display:fixed in .site.

That'll be a good start.